# How to upload content of Excel file through #MicrosoftGraph

Tags: node.js, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently generating a file on my file system using `xlsx` NodeJS library, I also have created empty file on OneDrive using `create item` end point (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/item_post_children)

Now, I want to upload content of the file on OneDrive with the content of the file that I have on the file system. I am trying to do this using `Upload Item` end point (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/item_uploadcontent) and the request is passing ok, but when I try to open the file with Excel Online I am getting message that the file is corrupted

Anyway, if I upload the file through the OneDrive web interface, everything works fine

Any idea why the content upload not working?

Comment: Hi Miloš, can you obtain a capture of your HTTP request with Fiddler or a similar tool, and see if the content being sent up matches what you expect? My guess is that your uploading code might be sending it in some encoded format, and the server isn't decoding it prior to storing it. Also, we recommend that you avoid creating an empty file before uploading content. Just upload the content in one shot. That way, if something goes wrong with your upload, you aren't stuck with an empty file that could be confusing to users.

Comment: How did you load your xlsx file? Obviously, using OneDriveSDK works for me. If you're using something like a WebClient to load your file, you'll need to watch out for the format, as daspek points out.

Comment: Hi @daspek, thanks for answer, I assumed that it is a problem, but I have issues to match the encoded format, last thing that I have found is that should be base64 encoded string, I have tired that also but not working

Do you know maybe which format is working? Documentation says nothing about it.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the file should be the binary stream of the file being uploaded. I created a sample web app for people to play with the Graph APIs called [Visual Graph Explorer](https://visualgraphexplorer.azurewebsites.net). Once you log on to the web app with O365 credentials, you can click on the Files link and upload a file. On the right you will see a log of the requests and responses. If you want to see the full source you can check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/dougperkes/Visual-Graph-Explorer).

The code I use for the upload is in JavaScript and runs on the client side.

```
var f = document.getElementById("inputFile").files[0];
var r = new FileReader();
r.onloadend = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + $scope.upn + "/drive/root/children/" + f.name + "/content";
        $http.put(url, data)
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                        document.getElementById("inputFile").value = "";
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        $scope.error = JSON.stringify(response);
                        $scope.loadingMessage = "";
                })
}
r.readAsBinaryString(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way maybe is to upload an empty Excel file and update the data using [Excel REST](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel) API.

Answer (score 0):

Upload it as binary file. Ruby code for uploading an excel file to onedrive

```
require 'net/http'

upload_path = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/children/test_file.xlsx/content'
request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(upload_path, {'Authorization': token })    
f= File.new(file_path, "r+b")
request.body = f.read
resp = https.request request
```